# How to hit different servers?

Tags: spring-boot

I have  3 layered mysql database ,where each schema is in different servers.I want to write java spring boot code to communicate with each service.How can I hit the url of the 1st one and from there to second one and from there to 3rd?

Comment: So you want to read/write to 3 database in the same time?

Comment: whenever i hit the url1 it has to redirect to another url2 and from there to url3 likewise.

Comment: You mean when you cal to db1, function of db1 should call to db2 and function of db2 call to db3.

Comment: @DumindaJayarathne yeah,exactly.I want to write rest service for that in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to declare multiple sources in a Spring Boot application, with different configurations (different DBs with different JBDC Url connections for example).

Here is an example of declaring one `@Primary` data source and two other ones in a Spring Boot application, and how it is configured:

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Hope it serves the purpose.